auto keyword usage with concepts
As shown in the cppreference.
The auto keyword can be used to get rid of template with concept.
// Constrained C++20 function template:
template<Hashable T>
void f(T) {}
//
// Alternative ways to apply the same constraint:
// template<typename T>
//     requires Hashable<T>
// void f(T) {}
//
// template<typename T>
// void f(T) requires Hashable<T> {}
//
void f(Hashable auto /* parameter-name */) {}

My question is how to use the same technic with auto when I have two template parameters.
template<typename T1, typename T2> concept MyConcept<T1, T2> = ....

template<typename T1, typename T2> 
void func(MyConcept<T1, T2> c) { ... }
// Why cannot use :
void func(MyConcept auto c) { ... }


If you need a requires constraint on your template, then you need a template.

c can be of any type, it is not constrained ... the constrain is on the template arguments, which have nothing to do with the function arguments ... you don't need MyConcept<T1,T2> before c, you only need to add auto or auto&&, your question after the edit makes no sense at all, unless you want to constrain the template arguments of c itself (ie: like constraining the T in vector<T>), in which case auto is also pointless.

you need to expand on your current example, what do you expect your MyConcept will do ? write that as plain text, like "i want c to support doing X"

I amended the question. I need to use auto to deduce T1 and T2 for MyConcept concept as it's done for Hashable one

MyConcept<T1, T2> = .... what is .... ? you didn't answer in the form "i want c to support doing X", in the code you posted T1 and T2 have nothing to do with c , how can a constraint constrain something that is not a constraint on the variable that it is constraining ??!!! you can't do it because it doesn't make sense.

You don't. This syntax only works in the simplest of cases. When a concept is based off of a single type template parameter, that type can be assumed to be the deduced type of the argument (and if it's not, then you'll have to do things differently anyway). But when a concept is based on multiple parameters, which one is the type for the argument, and where does the other type come from?
You have to spell it out long-form with a proper requires clause.
